# Best way to code custom loop to avoid str.format() key error in this example?

Tags: python, loops, keyerror

I want to output something that looks like this (with 20 items per line, and two variables are needed, one for indexing, i, and one for the book name, bookname, in this case `"Psalm"`):

```
\hyperlink{Psalm1}{1} & \hyperlink{Psalm2}{2} & \hyperlink{Psalm3}{3}  ...
```

Using Python (simplification of my loop, but enough to show the key error) I attempted:

```py
        for indx in range(1, 150, 20):
            line = r""" \\hline
\\hyperlink{{{bn}{i}}}{{{i}}}  & \\hyperlink{{{bn}{i+1}}}{{{i+1}}} & \\hyperlink{{{bn}{i+2}}}{{{i+2}}} ... 
""".format( i=indx, bn = bookname)
```

What's the best way to recode to avoid the `i+1` key error ?

Comment: what is `i+1` error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example of string generation (`\hyperlink{Psalm1}{1}`) using different methods:

```py
i = 1
# string concatenation
formatted = r"\hyperlink{Psalm" + str(i) + "}{" + str(i) + "}"
# old-style formatting
formatted = r"\hyperlink{Psalm%d}{%d}" % (i, i))
# str.format
formatted = r"\hyperlink{{Psalm{0}}}{{{0}}}".format(i)
# f-string
formatted = rf"\hyperlink{{Psalm{i}}}{{{i}}}"
```

For this particular case I find [*old-style formatting*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting) more "clean" as it doesn't require doubling curly brackets.

To print 20 strings in each line you can pass [*generator*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) which will produce formatted strings into [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

Full code:

```py
stop = 150
step = 20
for i in range(1, stop + 1, step):
    print(
        " & ".join(
            r"\hyperlink{Psalm%d}{%d}" % (n, n)
            for n in range(i, min(i + step, stop + 1))
        )
    )
```

Or you can also use "one-liner":

```py
stop = 150
step = 20
print(
    "\n".join(  # use " &\n".join(...) if you need trailing '&'
        " & ".join(
            r"\hyperlink{Psalm%d}{%d}" % (n, n)
            for n in range(i, min(i + step, stop + 1))
        )
        for i in range(1, stop + 1, step)
    )
)
```

Comment: I ended up doing something like this ... as I needed the bookname in the code as well as the "i" for chapter number ... this is why I initially had  ...format( bn=bookname, i=i).  Which inserted:  Genesis, Exodus, ... Psalm, ...  Revelation.

Comment: @RichWalt, could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69666515/edit) your question? Add details and it will be good to see expected output too.

Comment: @RichWalt, you edited your question but I still not sure why my answer doesn't fit. If you need one more variable, just add it `r"\hyperlink{%s%d}{%d}" % ("Psalm", n, n)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `f` string

```
for i in range(1, 150, 20):
  print(f"\\hyperlinkPPsalm{i} & \\hyperlinkPsalm{i+1} & \\hyperlinkPsalm{i+2}")
```

Comment: this would be fine, except that I need the bookname in this as well ... Genesis, Exodus, ... Psalm ... Revelation.  so the the  .format(bn = bookname, i = i ) was needed in the above example.

Comment: Try to add the book name. Do you have any question regarding the book name addition?